# Bootstrap 5 Carousel-fade slow transition

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap 5 Carousel with the fade effect and not having any luck. I need the images to slowly fade-in and fade-out. I've tried this solution: [Bootstrap Carousel - how to fade between slides slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169823/bootstrap-carousel-how-to-fade-between-slides-slowly)
and this one as well: [Bootstrap Carousel Fade Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294862/bootstrap-carousel-fade-transition)

Neither solutions work for Bootstrap 5 since it no longer uses jquery. Here is a pen that I created to test the effects:
[Codepen example][1]

I would appreciate some advice on how to slow down the transition and gradually fade-in and fade-out between each image.

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/JapperCat/live/KKWEeJa
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Bootstrap Carousel fade transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665392/change-bootstrap-carousel-fade-transition) ... "Neither solutions work for Bootstrap 5 since it no longer uses jquery". The carousel fade has nothing to do with JS/jQuery. It's all CSS. Use the CSS from the duplication question for Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to slow fade-in and fade-out transitions to 5 seconds between images

```
  .carousel-item {
    transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start,
  .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end {
    transition: opacity 0s 5s;
  }
```

I edited your pen on:
https://codepen.io/imazen/pen/BaWbbQz

Comment: Perfect! That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thank you